# How to ask permission for Bubble in my app?

Tags: android, permissions, android-10.0, android-bubbles

I am using bubble feature in my app for Android 10. So I need to ask permission to enable Bubble feature. If users agree to the permission, then need to go through the exact path of enabling it. How do I achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bubbles are not available for users on Android 10 -- it is a developer-only feature. Bubbles are enabled for users on Android R, and there is no permission needed to use them.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you..can we programmatically enable it?

Comment: On Android 10? Not that I am aware of. Those developer toggles usually are not exposed to be changed programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this for Android 11.

This first method will check if Bubbles are enabled or not.

```
/** Returns true if bubbles are enabled for this app */
private boolean canDisplayBubbles() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < MIN_SDK_BUBBLES) {
    return false;
  }

  // NotificationManager#areBubblesAllowed does not check if bubbles have been globally disabled,
  // so we use this check as well.
  boolean bubblesEnabledGlobally;
  try {
    bubblesEnabledGlobally = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), "notification_bubbles") == 1;
  } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
    // If we're not able to read the system setting, just assume the best case.
    bubblesEnabledGlobally = true;
  }

  NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
  return bubblesEnabledGlobally && notificationManager.areBubblesAllowed();
}
```

This second method will launch a settings page asking the user to give permission for your app to display Bubbles.

```
/** Launches a settings page requesting the user to enable Bubbles for this app */
private void requestBubblePermissions() {
  startActivityForResult(
    new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_BUBBLE_SETTINGS)
      .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName()),
    REQUEST_CODE_BUBBLES_PERMISSION);
}
```

Comment: Nice catch with the global settings. If disabled globally apps probably wants to send the user to `android.settings.NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` where that setting lives.

Comment: ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_BUBBLE_SETTINGS seemed to handle the case where it's globally disabled quite well, at least on Pixel, so I opted to not differentiate the two cases.